# Phantomjs:How to remove header footer only for the first page?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs to render pdf with header and footer. Adding header and footer is implemented in all pages. Is there any way to remove header/footer from 1st page alone?

```
 header: {
height: "1cm",
contents: phantom.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
  return "<h1>Header <span style='float:right'>" + pageNum + " / " + numPages + "</span></h1>";
})},  footer: {
height: "1cm",
contents: phantom.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
  return "<h1>Footer <span style='float:right'>" + pageNum + " / " + numPages + "</span></h1>";
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

While not perfect, I return and empty string instead of actual html content when pageNum is equal to 1 (or to numPages in my case). The height is still occupied but at least its empty.